# How can I prevent Slack from adding previews when I send links in a Slack message?

Tags: slack, links

I don't want  to have to  click on "remove preview" for each link each time I send a message:

[image]

Note: I don't want to turn off link previews for myself only, but  instead I want my messages not to have any previews for  anyone.

---

Example of a link preview:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround is to exclude `https://` from the links you share.

[Source (Slack help article)](https://slack.com/help/articles/360001502048-Manage-link-previews-for-your-workspace):

> Here are some reasons your link may not expand to show a preview:
> http:// was not included. Try adding http:// and your link should expand.

I tested it and for now (at the time of posting) it works for both regular chat messages and bot messages.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works.